# Problem with merging two data frames in R with different columns

Tags: r

I have a filtered dataframe `Id` that are as following.

```
ID    Bonus
35    25.54
36    24.32
37    43.23
38    24.43
39    34.21
40    23.12
```

I want to merge `Id` with the below dataframe `City`

```
ID   City       Lat_Long
35   Paris      list(67.14.6552, 67.33539)...
36   Oslo       list(70.24.5215, 62.53525)...
37   Berlin     list(62.54.3533, 64.63438)...
38   Rome       list(67.34.2458, 68.13539)...
39   London     list(65.54.6215, 69.23139)...
40   Barcelona  list(61.54.3055, 62.73520)...
41   Vilnius    list(64.54.6051, 61.23535)...
#With 500 more rows
```

So it is going to look like this `Id_city`

```
ID   City       Lat_Long                           Bonus
35   Paris      list(67.14.6552, 67.33539)...      25.54
36   Oslo       list(70.24.5215, 62.53525)...      24.32
37   Berlin     list(62.54.3533, 64.63438)...      43.23
38   Rome       list(67.34.2458, 68.13539)...      24.43
39   London     list(65.54.6215, 69.23139)...      34.21
40   Barcelona  list(61.54.3055, 62.73520)...      23.12
```

I have tried the join function `Id_city <- inner_join(Id, City, by = "ID")` which should work. However, I get error Column `Lat_long` is a `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON/sfc` object. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Please use the dput of the example to get the structure correctly

Comment: I think `tibble` does not understand  sfc_multipolyn/sfc  object. ->
Try: `library(sf)`

Comment: @TarJae You solved my problem!

Comment: Consider also the solution provided by akrun!

Answer (score 3):

It was a beginner mistake by me.

The tibble didn't  understood `sfc_multipolyn/sfc object`.

To solve it I needed to install  `library(sf)`.